# Listing skipped numbers in a large txt file using bash

Tags: bash

I need to find a way to display the missing numbers from a large txt file. It's a web graph that has 875,713 vertices. However, when I sort the file the largest number that is displayed at the end is 916,427. So there are some numbers not being used for vertex index. Is there a bash command I could use to do this?

I found this after searching around some other threads but I'm not entirely sure if its correct:

`awk 'NR != $1 { for (i = prev + 1; i < $1; i++) {print i} } { prev = $1 + 1 }' file`

Comment: I'm very happy that you have a solution to your problem, but for future reference, you'll have better luck getting answers if you follow the [How-to-ask guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a little more closely. In particular, you should provide sample input data, your work so far, you result (even if it's an error), and a sample of what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the 'number' of each vertex is in the first column, you can use:

```
awk '{a[$1]} END{for(i = 1; i <= 916427; i++){if(!(i in a)){print i}}}' file
```

E.g.

```
# create some example data and remove "10"
seq 916427 | sed '10d' > test.txt

head test.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
11

awk '{a[$1]} END { for (i = 1; i <= 916427; i++) { if (!(i in a)) {print i}}}' test.txt
10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to store the array in memory (otherwise @jared_mamrot solution would work), you can use

```
awk 'NR==1 {p=$1; next} {for (i=p+1; i<$1; i++) {print i}; p=$1}' < <( sort -n file)
```

which sorts the file first.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you tagged your question `bash`, I'll provide a bash solution. :)

```bash
# sample data as jared suggested, with 10 removed...
seq 916427 | sed '10d' > test.txt

# read sample data into an array...
mapfile -t a < test.txt

# reverse the $a array into $b
for i in "${a[@]}"; do b[$i]=1; done

# step through list of possible numbers, testing if each one is an index of $b
for ((i=1; i<${a[((${#a[@]}-1))]}; i++)); do [[ -z ${b[i]} ]] && echo $i; done
```

The line noise in the last line (`${a[((${#a[@]}-1))]}`) simply means "the value of the last array element", and the -1 is there because without instructions otherwise, `mapfile` starts numbering things at zero.

This takes a little longer to run than awk, because awk is awesome. But it runs in bash without calling any external tools. Aside from the ones generating our sample data, of course!

Note that the last line verifies `$b` array membership with a string comparison. You might get a very slight performance increase by doing a math comparison instead (`(( ${b[i]} )) || echo $i`) but the improvement would be so small that it's not even worth mentioning.  Oh dang.

Note also that both this and the awk solution involve creating very large arrays in memory, then stepping through those arrays. Be careful of your memory, and don't waste array space with unnecessary data. You will probably want to pull just your indices out of your original dataset for this comparison, rather than loading *everything* into a bash or awk array.